# Generate dummy customer data

Tags: python, performance

Just out of curiosity, I have this code lying around a personal project in which I will generate lots of dummy customer data.

Here's the code:

```
faker = Faker()
# Faker.seed(random.randint(0, sys.maxsize))


async def get_random_customer_login(count: int, user: CustomerLogin_PydanticIn) -> list:
    data = []

    for i in range(count):
        plain_email = user.plain_email
        user_ip = user.user_ip
        user_id = user.user_id
        client_id = user.client_id
        result = user.result
        fail_cause = user.fail_cause
        process = user.process
        user_agent = user.user_agent
        device_token = user.device_token
        event_timedate = user.event_timedate

        if plain_email is None:
            plain_email = await get_random_email()

        if user_ip is None:
            user_ip = await get_random_ip_address()

        if user_id is None:
            user_id = uuid.uuid4()

        if client_id is None:
            client_id = await get_random_client_id()

        if result is None:
            result = await get_random_result()

            if 'AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS' not in result:
                fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()
                if fail_cause is None:
                    fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()

        if process is None:
            process = await get_random_ub_process()

        if user_agent is None:
            user_agent = await get_random_user_agent()

        if device_token is None:
            device_token = uuid.uuid4()

        if event_timedate is None:
            event_timedate = await get_random_utc_timestamp()

        customer_login = CustomerLogin_PydanticIn(
            event_timedate=event_timedate,
            user_id=user_id,
            device_token=device_token,
            user_ip=user_ip,
            user_agent=user_agent,
            client_id=client_id,
            process=process,
            result=result,
            fail_cause=fail_cause,
            plain_email=plain_email)
        data.append(customer_login)
    return data


async def get_random_email() -> str:
    return faker.ascii_company_email()


async def get_random_ip_address() -> str:
    return faker.ipv4_public()


async def get_random_ub_process() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=PROCESS_LIST)


async def get_random_client_id() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=CLIENT_ID_LIST)


async def get_random_result() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=RESULT_LIST)


async def get_random_fail_cause() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=FAILURE_CAUSE_LIST)


async def get_random_user_agent() -> str:
    return faker.user_agent()


async def get_random_utc_timestamp() -> datetime.datetime:
    return pytz.utc.localize(faker.date_time_this_century())
```

Basically, this function takes in a `count` of dummy data to be created, and the `CustomerLogin` pydantic object. The catch is the function will assign some randomly generated value of fields in `CustomerLogin` that are not provided.

Anyway, this code works. However, I think there's a lot of room to optimize and should I set faker seed?

Comment: There is not much room for performance improvement, no, since all you are doing is a series of "if X is not set, assign this value to it".

Comment: You can probably extract all the variables that reference random objects to be created in a common get_random(element) function, that will call to faker.random_element(elements=element), so you don't have to do it so many times

Comment: Hi. I thinking more of a way to avoid the numerous if-else statements for the `CustomerLogin` pydantic model. Is there a way that I can for loop through them, check the values, and assign generated values if none provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Pydantic models

I am presuming the CustomerLogin_PydanticIn is a Pydantic model.

You can iterate over a Pydantic model to get the names and values of its fields.
We can do this to build a dict, `missing`, that maps fields in `user` with `None` values
to functions that generate random replacement values. The functions have a standard
name format, "random_(field_name)", so they can be looked up using `globals()`.

`new_attrs` uses the `missing` dict to create a dict mapping empty fields to
replacement values.

Field 'fail_cause' is handled separately. Note, the logic for `fail_cause` may need to be fixed. For example, it doesn't handle the case where user.result has a value
indicating failure but `fail_cause` is `None`.

Lastly, `user.copy` is used with the `update` parameter to create a new CustomerLogin_PydanticIn.

```
async def get_random_customer_login(count: int, user: CustomerLogin_PydanticIn) -> list:
    # map missing user attrs to functions that generate random attr values
    missing = {}
    for attr, value in user:
        if value is None and attr != 'fail_cause':
            missing[attr] = globals()[f"random_{attr}"] 
    
    data = []
    for _ in range(count):
        new_attrs = {attr:func() for attr, func in missing.items()}
        
        if 'result' in new_attrs and 'AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS' not in new_attrs['result']:
            fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()
            if fail_cause is None:
                fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()
            new_attrs['fail_cause'] = fail_cause
            
        data.append(user.copy(update=new_attrs))
        
    return data

async def random_client_id() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=CLIENT_ID_LIST)

async def random_device_token():
    return uuid.uuid4()

async def random_event_timedate() -> datetime.datetime:
    return pytz.utc.localize(faker.date_time_this_century())

async def random_fail_cause() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=FAILURE_CAUSE_LIST)

async def random_plain_email() -> str:
    return faker.ascii_company_email()

async def random_process() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=PROCESS_LIST)

async def random_result() -> str:
    return faker.random_element(elements=RESULT_LIST)

async def random_user_agent() -> str:
    return faker.user_agent()

async def random_user_id() -> str:
    return uuid.uuid4()

async def random_user_ip() -> str:
    return faker.ipv4_public()
```

Note, this code hasn't been tested.

#### faker.seed()

`faker` uses `random.Random` in the standard library.  An instance of `random.Random` initializes its seed from the time or a system random source. So setting a seed is not necessary. However, for testing it may be helpful to set the seed to a known value so as to get the same sequence of random values.

Answer (score 2):

I can't come up with many performance improvements, but I have a couple of suggestions for you.

**Dummy variable in the `for` loop**

You have a `for` loop that goes

```py
for i in range(count):
    # ...
```

but you do nothing with `i` because you just want to execute the function `i` times.
A very idiomatic way to say you don't *need* the variable is by writing

```py
for _ in range(count):
```

It saves people the time of looking for the usage of `i` inside the loop.

**One item per line, end line with comma on long lists**

You have a long list of kwargs that you pass in to `CustomerLogin_PydanticIn`, and in those cases it is better to have a kwarg per line and ending every line with a comma. You *almost* do this, you are just missing the last line:

```py
customer_login = CustomerLogin_PydanticIn(
    event_timedate=event_timedate,
    # ...
    plain_email=plain_email,
)
```

This apparently tiny change will be more git friendly if/when you need to add/remove kwargs.

**Short circuiting**

Finally, for the sake of completeness (as this was already mentioned in other answers) you can use short-circuiting for the `None` checks:

```py
plain_email = user.plain_email
if plain_email is None:
    plain_email = await get_random_email()
```

becomes

```py
plain_email = user.plain_email or await get_random_email()
```

**Double fail cause..?**

Your code reads:

```py
        if result is None:
            result = await get_random_result()

            if 'AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS' not in result:
                fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()
                if fail_cause is None:
                    fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()
```

In particular, you do `fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()` and if `fail_cause` is `None`, you do *the exact same line* again, but only once more.
*What if* `fail_cause` is still `None`? Maybe you know that `get_random_fail_cause` doesn't return two `None`s in a row?
Assuming you don't know that for sure, you would probably write a `while` loop:

```py
fail_cause = None
while fail_cause is None:
    fail_cause = await get_random_fail_cause()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this. I have learned something new.

Comment: @akuani my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Since most of your checks are simply checking that a value hasn't already been provided, you can use the `or` operator to remove most of the if statements. e.g.

```py
>>> print(None or "I've used the 'or' operator")
I've used the 'or' operator
```

Since the value left of the `or` is `None` the right-hand side is evaluated.